# Best way to check multiple tasks done in Celery?

Tags: python, celery, jobs, worker

After some research , I found the more problems... 
Below is more detailed Emxaple:

1. upload a list of urls, set a job_id to all of them(need generate a dynamically queue name for purging).
2. use Celery tasks to crawl each url, such as `extract.delay(job_id, url)` and save to db.
3. (maybe here are many job --- job1, job2, job3) all tasks in jobs are same `extract`, just one worker process all the queue(How ? I can not tell all queue name to the worker )
4. check db `select count(id) in xxx where job_id = yyy` equal to `len(urls)`,
   or other way as Celery tell me `job_id yyy` has done.
5. show this job status(running or complete) in website, can purge job queue on web.

I have never meet this situation, is celery has some easy way to solve my problem?

I need add a job dynamically, one job contain a lot of tasks. All tasks are same .How can I make different jobs have diferent queue name, and just one worker process all the queues? In programmatically.

Comment: Do you want to know how many are done or just if all of them are done?  If you just want all of them as done have you considered using a group?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your web app, but this can be pretty straightforward.

(Using Django syntax)

you could make two models/DB tables. One to represent your batch. And one to represent each URL job

```
class ScrapeBatch(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField()

class ScrapeJob(models.Model):
   batch = models.ForeignKey(ScrapeBatch)
   url = models.CharField(max_length=100) # for example
   done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then, when you run your celery tasks, use the `ScrapeJob` model as your reference

```
def scrape_url_celery_task(job_id):
     job = ScrapeJob.objects.get(id=job_id)
     scrape_url(job)
     job.done=True
     job.save()
```

So in your webview, you could simply check if all your batch's jobs are done or not:

```
def batch_done(batch):
    return not batch.scrapejob_set.filter(done=False).exists()
```

So in summary:
  - A DB table that holds your URLS
  - A DB table to hold something like a batch number (with foreign key relations to your URL table)

- celery marks URLs as scraped in the DB after the task is completed
- A simple search through the URL table tells you whether the job is done. You can show this value on a website

Comment: My current code is just like you, but I think check db every time is not very good.That's why I want to know is there a better way provided, such as a notification or somtthing else to deal with such problem by celery.